# Store secrets in a Django application running with docker on a DigitalOcean

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, digital-ocean, django-3.0

I am curious what is the best way to safely store secrets (passwords, secret keys, etc.) in a Django app on a server.

Previously I used Heroku with Git and all the secrets were stored in Heroku's environment using the web interface.
Then I could just use `os.environ['secret_key']` to get secrets.

Now I am trying to deploy to DigitalOcean server using Docker-Compose. I've read about the [docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), but it appeared to be insecure.

I can also store them in a JSON file, but I am not sure if it's secure also. Probably, then they should be encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are a common practice to store application secrets. That said, the values for these variables should not live in your (source-controlled-) docker-compose.

To specify that a variable should be transferred from the host to the container, you just use the variable name without value:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: 
      SECRET_KEY:
```

Then, you can choose various ways to have these variables on your server. One way is to have an [`.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) with these values. For example:

```
# .env
SECRET_KEY=123
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://admin:s3cr3tz@db/mydb
```

This file of course is not committed to the git repository, and is kept in confidence.

Using the above `docker-compose.yml` and `.env`, you can run `docker-compose config` to see the complete output:

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: /vagrant/temp
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://admin:s3cr3tz@db/mydb
      SECRET_KEY: '123'
version: '3.0'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems like I need just to choose the way in which I can set up this env file on my server.